# group by access seperate column

Tags: sql, ms-access, select, group-by

I'm very new to SQL and have the following (seemingly simple) database query.

I have a table containing all timetracking information for a set of employees:

```
date        employeeId timeIn timeOut
01/01/20    1355       12:00  4:00
01/01/20    1355       4:30   6:00
01/01/15    1234       9:00   12:00
02/01/15    5555       5:00   6:00
02/01/15    1111       1:00   4:00
```

foreach date, I want to count the number of unique employees that worked, ending with a table like:

```
date      totalEmployeesWorked
01/01/15  2
02/01/15  2
```

There are several Id's I would like to ignore as well. So far I came up with:

I have tried the following query in MS Access 2003:

```
SELECT [TimeTrackingLog-sql].date, COUNT(DISTINCT callerName)
FROM [TimeTrackingLog-sql]
GROUP by [TimeTrackingLog-sql].date
```

and it complained about a 'missing operator', highlighting my use of callerName.

Comment: `count` itself is an aggregate function. Can you clarify the problem a bit? Are you getting an error message? The wrong result?

Comment: I updated the original post with my attempt, sorry for the lack of clarity

Comment: better to add sample data and expected output?

Comment: Please ensure that you use the correct tag when creating a question.  Removed `mysql` tag as this invited an answer that won't work in the actual database you are using (MS Access).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The good news is that your query is perfectly legal (and straight forward!) ANSI SQL, that will work on any sensible database. The bad news is that MS Access which you're using does not support this syntax.

It can be worked around with a subquery, though:

```
SELECT   t.date, COUNT(*)
FROM     (SELECT DISTINCT [TimeTrackingLog-sql].date, 
                          [TimeTrackingLog-sql].callerName
          FROM   [TimeTrackingLog-sql]) t
GROUP BY t.date
```

Comment: You have a slight mistake in your SQL.  The bracket after `callername` should be removed.

Comment: @MartinParkin - thanks for noticing (damn typos! :( ). Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:-

```
SELECT date, count(distinct `employeeId`) FROM `table_name` group by date;
```

Comment: The question was incorrectly tagged as `mysql`.  It's actually in MS Access, which renders your answer incorrect (although it would work in `mysql`).